# Table auto cleaning in oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-data

I'm writing Java Web application. I'm using Spring DATA with Oracle. I want that, table would be auto cleaning everyday at the midnight. I know, there is "TRUNCATE TABLE table_name" but I want declare a something like procedure to auto cleaning. Is that possible?

**-- EDIT -- EDIT**

More information... It is daily diary application, something like noty. Thats why I would delete all rows from table. So truncate is a good way?

Comment: You can create a procedure that does the truncate and then use the `dbms_scheduler` package to schedule a job that truncates the table at midnight.  That seems like a rather odd architectural choice, though.  If this is really transitory data, are you sure that you don't want to use a temporary table or some other construct and/or purge the data more selectively in response to other events?

Comment: You may want to check interval partitioning to remove older data. DELETE is ugly for large numer of records and TRUNCATE will fail if there are open transaction at that time...

Comment: Guys, update first post, something about application. If you have a better way for that, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You could set something up with DBMS_Scheduler, but I would try to avoid relying on Truncate unless you knew you had a clear window between midnight and a few minutes past midnight when it was guaranteed that no new rows would be added, or you'd lose them also.

It's safer to run something like:

```
delete from my_table where created_at < trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: I'd want more than a few minutes.  Jobs don't always run right when they're scheduled.  And consider what happens if, say, your database is down at midnight (or jobs are disabled) for patching/ upgrades/ code pushes so your job runs at 3 or 4am once the database restarts/ re-enables jobs.

Comment: @JustinCave yes, good points. The whole thing is very not-recommended.

Comment: Guys, update first post, something about application. If you have a better way for that, please tell me.